# Rails/MySQL: better to use JSON column or serialized text for non-JSON use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activerecord

With my Rails 7.1.3 app, I have have a MySQL 8 db with a table `users`. Each user has many `translations`, and the translations belong to another table `languages`.

I'd like to cache the results of a query counting a user's `translations` broken down by `language`, ideally stored in a way I can retrieve it as an object like

```
{ es: 1754, pt: 353, ru: 23, zh: 2334 }
```

- I'm not going to query on this data, or send it to a front-end.
- This data is just for internal use, and it is presentational. It is used on a user's profile page to show an approximate count of their work to date.
- The data is not coming from users, it's coming from the app. It's a query of the db with counts; all values are integers. It's refreshed once a day by a cron job, and it's not critical that it be accurate up-to-the minute.

**Question:** What's the best kind of column to store this stuff? Serialized text column, JSON column, or something else?

I've never used a JSON column before in Rails. Do I need to create a JSON schema to validate that kind of column?

Or is this the wrong use case for a JSON column? (The hash doesn't need to be sent as JSON, I just like that it's a formatted hash. But so is a serialized column.)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why this query is run on a cron?

This seems like a great case for a caching layer. Allow your Rails cache store the ability to hold on to query results, give it a sensible time to live, and automatically query for a fresh data set when no valid one exists.

```
Rails.cache.fetch("user_translations_for_#{user.id}", expires_in: 1.hour) do
  query_goes_here
end
```

More on rails caching here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Thanks - The query is run on a cron because the data does not get reliably incremented by Rails. I don't really want to cache it and then run the query on demand (upon user access of the page) when it expires, even with a reasonable expiration date, because the query is too expensive. This a page where all of the data is derived and throwaway-quality, but it's currently queried on demand and it's too slow. A cron (i.e. data that is "baked last night") seems to offer a reasonable tradeoff between stale data and slow page loads.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: What's the best kind of column to store this stuff?
> Serialized text column, JSON column, or something else?

The only reason you would ever want to use a serialized text column in 2024 is if you need application level encryption and are storing the resulting encrypted hash.

Using a JSON column on the users table is a simple and somewhat enticing solution but the major cons are that it has no data normalization. While you can have a JSON schema validate whatever you want on the application level there are no guarentees on the database level about the structure of the data. See [PostgreSQL anti-patterns: Unnecessary json](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/).

Since the data is just aggregates generated from a database query I would consider using a [view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) if your database supports it. This is the result set from a stored query and behaves like a normal table.

The advantages is that the view and it's columns are defined in the schema so you don't have to deal with raw and potentially denormalized data, since views behave like a table you can define a model and assocations. You also don't have to update the `users` table with new aggregates which removes the need for the cron job.

The disadvantage is that you need to change the Rails schema dumps from Ruby to SQL and that your code will be less portable.

See:

- [Scenic Gem](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic)
- [Postgres Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-views.html)
- [MySQL views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html)

Comment: A view can be used in conjunction with the rails cache as in @vinyl's answer.

Comment: Thanks, views are really counter-intuitive to me. Would you use views for the common use case of "user preferences" also? A lot of people use serialized columns for those, so they don't have to do a migration every time the preferences change.

Comment: @nimmolo - no that's not something you would use a view for. Views are used for data that is fetched through a database query such as aggregates (think the stats for a sports team). Not for data that originates from the user.

Comment: A lot of people use *stuctured* column types such as JSON columns - usually unnessicarily. Not serialized columns which are a hacky solution from the dark ages and don't let you query the data in any sane way.

Comment: Re: columns, that makes sense, and I understand the hackiness of old-school serialized columns. But... so, would JSON columns be advisable in that typical user-prefs case? We're trying to minimize frivolous migrations and user prefs are just not queried very often. Re: views, Scenic sounds like a nice way to do it, but we're not able to switch to PostgreSQL anytime soon.

Comment: (meant to say _materialized_ views seem like the thing we want, and only PG supports that)

Comment: @nimmolo - lets put it this way - JSON columns are a very useful tool for a handful of situations but should not be the "default" solution for anything. "Frivolous" migrations are also less of a problem than you would think if you're actually using migrations correctly. They are only intended to live in the codebase until the have been run across environments. After that they should be deleted. Using a JSON column because "waaah many migrations" doesn't sound like a good argument to me.

Comment: Instead weigh if you actually need to have a dynamic schema vs having defined columns with sensible types.